# Variable won't store data in powershell

Tags: variables, powershell

For some reason I can't get this variable ($SelectedDrive) to store data in it using the Get-Content cmdlet.

I have created a function as shown below:

```
#Allow user to select which drive to backup to and checks that the user hasn't canceled out of the Drive Selection GUI
Function SelectDrive{
ShowUSBs | Out-File $locBackupFolder\RemovableStorage.txt
Get-Content $locBackupFolder\RemovableStorage.txt | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title "Choose USB Storage Device" | Out-File $locBackupFolder\Drive.txt -Encoding default
$SelectedDrive = Get-Content $locBackupFolder\Drive.txt
IF ($SelectedDrive -eq $null) {
    WarningCancel
    RemoveBackupDrive
    Exit
    } ELSE {
    $BackupDrive = $SelectedDrive.Substring(0,2)
    }
}
```

When I run the script in Powershell ISE using the F5 button it runs through, and then fails to enter the data.

I go back and check it over and can't see any issue, as it works if I run it piece by piece using Run Selection.

The whole script is below:

```
######### DEFINE FUNCTIONS #########
$locBackupFolder =  "C:\Backup"

#Check Backup Drive
IF (!(Test-Path $locBackupFolder)) {
    #C:\Backup does NOT exist
    New-Item $locBackupFolder -ItemType Directory
}

#Inform user only D:\Username will be backed up
function WarningDialog(
$MessageWarning = "!!!WARNING!!!

YOU MAY LOSE DATA IF YOU DO NOT ADHERE TO THIS MESSAGE

Only D:\$env:USERNAME will be backed up, please ensure any Data that is sitting in the root of D:\ is moved to D:\$env:USERNAME

FYI: Your desktop data is safe and will be backed up, you need only worry about data in the root of D:\ or anything you have stored in 
C:\ Drive.

FURTHER MORE Outlook will shutdown by itself through this process, please do not open it up again until everything is finished.

If you have data to move, please click Cancel now, otherwise please press OK to continue the backup procedure.

For any help, please see your IT Technicians, or call
off-site.",

$WindowTitleWarning = "Backup your data from your laptop",
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]$ButtonsWarning = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OKCancel,
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]$IconWarning = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Stop
)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    return [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($MessageWarning, $WindowTitleWarning, $ButtonsWarning, $IconWarning)
}

#Checks to see if logged on user has a D:\USERNAME directory and if not, informs them to see IT for a custom backup.
Function TestUserDrive {
    IF (!(Test-Path "D:\$env:USERNAME")){
        #D:\USERNAME does NOT exist
    }
}

#Displays an instruction/how-to of how to move data from the root of D:\ to the users D:\USERNAME folder
function WarningCancel(
$MessageCancel = "INSTRUCTIONS:

You have chosen to cancel the backup script, if this is due to requiring data to be moved to inside your D:\$env:USERNAME folder, please do the following.

1. Open My Computer

2. Double click on Data (D:) to open your D:\ Drive

3. Move or Copy anything from this directory that you wish to keep, into the directory called $env:USERNAME\My Documents

4. Once this has been completed, re-run this script to commence the backup procedure again

Easy as that!

For any help, please see your IT Technicians, or call
off-site",
$WindowTitleCancel = "Backup your data from your laptop",
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]$ButtonsCancel = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK,
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]$IconCancel = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information
)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    return [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($MessageCancel, $WindowTitleCancel, $ButtonsCancel, $IconCancel)
}

#Informs the user to select the device they would like to backup to when the selection box is displayed
function SelectDevicePrompt(
$MessageSelect = "On the next screen please specify the device you would like to backup your data to.

The devices you currently have plugged in will show, please select your chosen device, and then click the OK button at the bottom right of the window.",

$WindowTitleSelect = "Backup your data from your laptop",
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]$ButtonsSelect = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK,
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]$IconSelect = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Hand
)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    return [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($MessageSelect, $WindowTitleSelect, $ButtonsSelect, $IconSelect)
}

#Displays a list of all removable storage devices volume names and their allocated drive letter
Function ShowUSBs{
$USBInfo = gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"} | %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |  %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"}
$USBInfo | Format-Table `
    @{Expression={$_.DeviceID};Label="Drive Letter";Width=25}, `
    @{Expression={$_.VolumeName};Label="USB Name";Width=20}
}

#Allow user to select which drive to backup to and checks that the user hasn't canceled out of the Drive Selection GUI
Function SelectDrive{
ShowUSBs | Out-File $locBackupFolder\RemovableStorage.txt
Get-Content $locBackupFolder\RemovableStorage.txt | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title "Choose USB Storage Device" | Out-File $locBackupFolder\Drive.txt -Encoding default
$SelectedDrive = Get-Content $locBackupFolder\Drive.txt
IF ($SelectedDrive -eq $null) {
    WarningCancel
    RemoveBackupDrive
    Exit
    } ELSE {
    $BackupDrive = $SelectedDrive.Substring(0,2)
    }
}
$BackupDrive

#Imports list of active processes and looks for outlook process then kills it if found
function KillOutlook{
$processactive = Get-Process
IF($processactive.ProcessName -contains "Outlook") {
    Stop-Process -Name Outlook
    Start-Sleep 1
    $OLcheckagain =  Get-Process
    IF($OLcheckagain.Processname -contains "Outlook") {
        Write-Host "Outlook failed to close"
        }
    } Else {
    Write-Host "Outlook is closed"
    }
}

#Find the pst files attached to outlook and output the values to C:\Backup\PST.txt
function FindPSTs{
$outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
$pstloc = $outlook.Session.Stores | where { ($_.FilePath -like '*.PST') }
$pstloc.FilePath | out-file -FilePath "$locBackupFolder\PST.txt" -Encoding Default
}

#Removes C:\Backup Directory
Function RemoveBackupDrive {
    IF (Test-Path $locBackupFolder){
    Remove-Item $locBackupFolder -Force -Recurse
    }
}

#Copy data from D:\USERNAME to BackupDrive
Function CopyData {
    IF (!(Test-Path $BackupDrive)) {
    robocopy D:\$env:USERNAME $BackupDrive /MIR /COPYALL /r:03 /w:5 /MT:9
    } ELSE {
    robocopy D:\$env:USERNAME $BackupDrive /
    }
}

#Copy PST files explicitly to BackupDrive\AppData\Roaming\Email
Function CopyPST {
    KillOutlook
    Start-Sleep 1
    IF (!(Test-Path $BackupDrive\AppData\Roaming\Email)) {
    New-Item $BackupDrive\AppData\Roaming\Email -ItemType Directory
    }
    Get-Content $locBackupFolder\PST.txt | ForEach-Object {
        IF (Test-Path $_){
        Copy-Item $_ "$BackupDrive\AppData\Roaming\Email"
        }
    }
}


######### START SCRIPT #########

#Display warning to inform user that only D:\USERNAME will be backed up
$WarningAccept = WarningDialog

#If cancel is selected from WarningDialog, then display WarningCancel message pop-up giving instructions to backup data from D:\ to D:\USERNAME
IF ($WarningAccept -eq "Cancel") {
WarningCancel
RemoveBackupDrive
Exit
}

#Prompts user to select Device to backup to
SelectDevicePrompt

#Shows the selection page for the user to select the device
SelectDrive

#Find the pst files attached to outlook and output to C:\Backup\PST.txt
FindPSTs

#Inform user where their data will be backed up to
Write-Host "Your data will be backed up to $BackupDrive"

#If Outlook is found, stop its process, otherwise continue
KillOutlook

#Running backup of everything in D:\ drive using robocopy
#If this is the first time copying all data /MIR will be used, otherwise if the directory DRIVE:\USERNAME\Backup exists
#robocopy will not /MIR and will only update newly added data.
CopyData

#Copy PST files specifically
#CopyPST
```

If I can be of any further assistance, please let me know.

Comment: Did you manually check the contents of file at `$locBackupFolder\Drive.txt`? Is it empty, or has data?

Comment: Hi @VikasGupta I checked the contents of the Drive.txt file and yes it has data inside it.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "fails to enter the data". Enter where? What is the content of `$SelectedDrive` after rading the file, and which operation exactly fails?

Comment: Hi again @AnsgarWiechers the string located in Drive.txt should be loaded into the variable $SelectedDrive however when the script is run in Powershell ISE by pressing F5 button, it doesn't work, it throws an error saying it can't proceed because the variable has nothing in it. I'm not at work anymore sorry and won't be for another 2 days as its Friday here. But I'll test everything on Monday and get back to you if you have any ideas.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but why are you piping the selection into a file at all? Why not just use `$selectedDrive = Get-Content $locBackupFolder\RemovableStorage.txt | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title "Choose USB Storage Device"` and then you have the actual drive object in a variable? If you still want the file you can write that separately from the variable.

Comment: @Duncan Thanks for the tip, I just tried it now, and unfortunately when I run the script in full it doesn't work, but when I run the command as 'Run Selection' it works, then I run the IF statement to trim to just the first two letters and it works too, then I run the variable to see what's stored inside it and it also work. So why does it not work when the script is run in full :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is simply that the `SelectDrive` function doesn't return anything. `$backupDrive` is local to the function, so you cannot refer to it from outside the function.

Also converting everything to text is going to introduce other bugs, e.g. you can select any line from the grid view including your headers and the blank lines top and bottom. Some better code might be:

```
Function GetUSBs{
    $USBInfo = gwmi win32_diskdrive |
        ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"} |
        %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |
        %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"}
    Write-Output $USBInfo | select @{n="Drive Letter";e={$_.DeviceID}},@{n="USB Name";e={$_.VolumeName}}
}

Function SelectDrive{
    $usbs = GetUSBs 
    $usbs |  Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File $locBackupFolder\RemovableStorage.txt

    $selectedDrive = $usbs | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title "Choose USB Storage Device"
    $selectedDrive | Out-File $locBackupFolder\Drive.txt -Encoding default

    if ($SelectedDrive -eq $null) {
        WarningCancel
        RemoveBackupDrive
        exit
    } else {
    write-output $selectedDrive.'Drive Letter'.Substring(0,2)
    }
}
$backupDrive = SelectDrive
```

This version still writes to your two files, but it doesn't read either of them, instead it keeps the objects internally. This means you get a better display in the grid view as the grid's own column headings are used, and you don't get any selectable lines you don't want.

Comment: Mate you are a friggen genius! Thank you so much, not only did you help me out, you also made the script better! KUDOS!!!

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on in your script, I debugged through it myself and found that these lines are causing the problems

```
ShowUSBs | Out-File $locBackupFolder\RemovableStorage.txt
Get-Content $locBackupFolder\RemovableStorage.txt | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title "Choose USB Storage Device" | Out-File $locBackupFolder\Drive.txt -Encoding default
$SelectedDrive = Get-Content "$locBackupFolder\Drive.txt"
```

You need to remove this block of code:

```
Out-File $locBackupFolder\Drive.txt -Encoding default
```

It is creating a new blank `Drive.txt` file, after which, `Get-Content` is being called on that empty file.

Therefore, it is getting the content of a blank file, which will always result in the `$SelectedDrive` variable being set to null.

I've added content to my `Drive.txt` file after this block has been removed and the `$SelectedDrive` variable is set to the content of the file as expected

Comment: Thanks @ShaneC however when the user clicks on the drive they would like to select to backup to, then click OK, the selected data that is in the Out-GridView writes back to the txt file. In the older Powershell version out-gridview only displays data however in the new Powershell version it allows you to select and pass data back, are you using windows 8.1? I am?

Comment: I am using 8.1, everytime I ran your code the drive file was overwritten by a blank file. Your code assumes that the $locBackupFolder exists and has files in it. Even though that directory is created earlier on in your script if it does not exist. You're creating dependencies on the content of files that might not even exist

Answer (score 0):

This construct won't work as you seem to expect:

```psh
Get-Content file | Out-GridView | Out-File otherfile
```

`Out-GridView` doesn't pass the data back into the pipeline for further processing. If you need data in both a grid view *and* a file you need to use the [`Tee-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) cmdlet before `Out-GridView`:

```psh
Get-Content file | Tee-Object otherfile | Out-GridView
```

In your case:

```psh
Get-Content "$locBackupFolder\RemovableStorage.txt" |
  Tee-Object "$locBackupFolder\Drive.txt" |
  Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title 'Choose USB Storage Device'
```

If you want the user to *select* a particular Item, `Out-GridView` won't work at all, because it's for *output* only (hence the verb `Out`). You'll need a [form with a list box](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730949.aspx) to allow the user to select an item:

```psh
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

$frm = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form

$btn = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$btn.Location = New-Object Drawing.Size(10,220)
$btn.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(75,23)
$btn.Text = "OK"
$btn.Add_Click({$frm.Close()})
$frm.Controls.Add($btn)

$list = New-Object Windows.Forms.ListBox
$list.Location = New-Object Drawing.Size(10,10)
$list.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(260,40)
$list.Height = 200
Get-Content "$locBackupFolder\RemovableStorage.txt" | % {
  $list.Items.Add($_)
} | Out-Null
$frm.Controls.Add($list)

$frm.Add_Shown({$frm.Activate()})
[void]$frm.ShowDialog()

$SelectedDrive = $list.SelectedItem
```

Comment: Hi @AnsgarWiechers in the latest version of Powershell the Out-GridView allows you to select and then output the selection. I have the output from the Out-GridView working fine, and it outputs to the $locBackupFolder\drive.txt, it's just the next part (Get-Content) that isn't working for me.

Comment: @Random206 Define "isn't working for me". What is the actual result of the operation, and how does that differ from the desired result?

Comment: defining "isn't working for me"... The variable $SelectedDrive is empty when it should contain the string inside the $locbackupfolder\Drive.txt once this is loaded into the variable then $BackupDrive takes the first 2 letters from the string, and concatenates another string onto the end of it. However it can't do this because the $SelectedDrive variable is blank to start with.